# Google Cloud Instance times out randomly after several hours?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm not sure whether this is an issue with Ubuntu or GCP but I'm not receiving any error in the LogsViewer when this occurs. I use this instance to make a network request every two seconds and I believe this is the cause but no idea how to stop it. The instance will work fine for around 12 hours before it times itself out. I'm unable to connect via SSH (even when using Putty) or even SFTP. In order to fix it, I must restart the instance but I'm sure there's a better solution to solve it permanently.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the story?  What I'm hearing is that you have a Linux Compute Engine running.  You then say that this instance is making a network request every 2 seconds ... what does that mean?  What is it doing?  I think you are then saying that after about 12 hours, your GCP VM is no longer responsive and you can't login via SSH.  Is that correct?  Maybe have a look at the machine using Stackdriver Metrics ... could you have a memory leak or be filling disk storage?

Comment: Or a socket leak